# How treat as one all row data that are alike in oracle query?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc

I have a system where in I need to get all messages that are stored in a SMS Gateway called tg800.

I am developing this using Spring MVC running in tomcat.

I am storing all received messages to a table called

```
SMS_MESSAGES

CREATE TABLE CWMS_USER.SMS_MESSAGES
(
  MESSAGE_ID             VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  SENDER                 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  SMSC                   VARCHAR2(13 CHAR),
  PORT_ID                VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  CONTENT                VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  RECEIVE_TIME           VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  HAS_READ               VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),
  IS_ASSIGNED_TO_TICKET  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  ID                     NUMBER                 NOT NULL,
  MESSAGE_STATUS         VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  TYPE_OF_MESSAGE        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)      NOT NULL
 )
```

I am storing all sent messages to a table called

```
SMS_REPLY

CREATE TABLE CWMS_USER.SMS_REPLY
(
  MESSAGE_ID             VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  SENDER                 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  SMSC                   VARCHAR2(13 CHAR),
  PORT_ID                VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  CONTENT                VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  RECEIVE_TIME           VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  HAS_READ               VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),
  IS_ASSIGNED_TO_TICKET  VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  ID                     NUMBER                 NOT NULL,
  MESSAGE_STATUS         VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  TYPE_OF_MESSAGE        VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)      NOT NULL
)
```

When you open a messaging app you'll see the number,latest message,date received and more. Ordered by date and grouped by number. That's what I need to see.

The problem I have is that TG800 is storing the numbers differently.

example:
in SMS_MESSAGES
the number is +639183478372

in SMS_REPLY
the number is 639183478372

The query is not treating these two numbers as one because the number in SMS_MESSAGES has a plus sign.

I have no control on how TG800 stores the number.

Is there any way to treat this as one?

```
SELECT * FROM((SELECT * FROM SMS_MESSAGES
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NO FROM SMS_CONTACTS) foo
    ON SMS_MESSAGES.SENDER = foo.CONTACT_NO)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM SMS_REPLY
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NO FROM SMS_CONTACTS) foo
    ON SMS_REPLY.SENDER = foo.CONTACT_NO)) WHERE (SENDER, RECEIVE_TIME) 
            IN (SELECT SENDER, MAX(RECEIVE_TIME) FROM ((SELECT * FROM SMS_MESSAGES
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NO FROM SMS_CONTACTS) foo
    ON SMS_MESSAGES.SENDER = foo.CONTACT_NO)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM SMS_REPLY
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_NO FROM SMS_CONTACTS) foo
    ON SMS_REPLY.SENDER = foo.CONTACT_NO)) GROUP BY SENDER,PORT_ID) ORDER BY RECEIVE_TIME desc
```

This is the query that I am using, It is not treating the same number as one.

I need to make this as one, because they are the same number. Kindly help me please.

Comment: You can add +(plus) sign at  SMS_REPLY .SENDER during comparation.  '+'||SENDER=foo.CONTACT_NO

Comment: When you say *"the number"* what column are you referring to? MESSAGE_ID? SENDER? Presumably not ID (as it is a number datatype).

Comment: @mfe I'll try that, but I also had another idea, your's is much easier so I'll try that. thanks!

Comment: @APC its the sender :)

Comment: @PatrickBrianGarcia you are welcome.